# Ubuntu 22.04 Shutter disabled

Tags: screenshot

After upgrading my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.  I opened the Shutter application, and I noticed that the selection and window were disabled.
[Disabled Select and Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inpxU.png)

I need to use shutter because it is more convenient to add a custom shortcut for repeated screenshots "shutter -r" rather than selecting all the time and also to avoid those snapping sounds that Ubuntu usually produces with their default screenshot. I had no problem previously when I was using Ubuntu 20.04.  Not sure why it got disabled after my upgrade.

Any tip or lead would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

A community member suggested a similar question, and I found the solution on the thread and it goes like this:
Reboot the computer and on arriving at the request for login, click on your name, then go down to the little cog in the bottom right of the screen a select Ubuntu on Xorg, then enter your password, and shutter is back to normal.

Comment: This worked. OBS also works with this. Tradeoff is fancy trackpad gestures no longer function.

Comment: Seems like a weird bug b/c I assumed that it was already using XOrg due to having Nvidia. This saved me thanks so much!